# Does Deployment Manager have Cloud Functions support (and support for having multiple cloud functions)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-deployment-manager

I'm looking at this repo and very confused about what's happening here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/tree/master/examples/v2/cloud_functions

In other Deployment Manager examples I see the "type" is set to the type of resource being deployed but in this example I see this:

```
resources:
- name: function
  type: cloud_function.py # why not "type: cloudfunctions"?
  properties:
    # All the files that start with this prefix will be packed in the Cloud Function
    codeLocation: function/
    codeBucket: mybucket
    codeBucketObject: function.zip
    location: us-central1
    timeout: 60s
    runtime: nodejs8
    availableMemoryMb: 256
    entryPoint: handler
```

"type" is pointing to a python script (cloud_function.py) instead of a resource type. The script is over 100 lines long and does a whole bunch of stuff.

This looks like a hack, like its just scripting the GCP APIs? The reason I'd ever want to use something like Deployment Manager is to avoid a mess of deployment scripts but this looks like it's more spaghetti.

Does Deployment Manager not support Cloud Functions and this is a hacky workaround or is this how its supposed to work? The docs for this example are bad so I don't know what's happening

Also, I want to deploy multiple function into a single Deployment Manager stack- will have to edit the `cloud_function.py` script or can I just define multiple resources and have them all point to the same script?

### Edit

I'm also confused about what these two imports are for at the top of the cloud_function.yaml:

```
imports:
# The function code will be defined for the files in function/
- path: function/index.js
- path: function/package.json
```

Why is it importing the actual code of the function it's deploying?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Deployment manager simply interacts with the different kind of Google APIs. This [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/supported-resource-types) gives you a list of supported resource types by Deployment manager. I would recommend you to run this command “gcloud deployment-manager types list | grep function”  and you will find  this “cloudfunctions.v1beta2.function” resource type is also supported by DM.

The template is using a [gcp-type](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/supported-gcp-types) (that is in beta).The cloud_functions.py is a [template](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/step-by-step-guide/create-a-template). If you use a template, you can reuse it for multiple resources, you can this see [example](https://github.com/Aahzymandius/deployment-manager/blob/master/working-env/resources.yaml).  For better understanding, easier to read/follow you can check this [example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/tree/master/google/resource-snippets/cloudfunctions-v1) of cloud functions through gcp-type.

Answer (score 2):

I wan to add to the answer by *Aarti S* that `gcloud deployment-manager types list | grep function` doesn't work for me as I found [how to all list of resource types, including resources that are in alpha](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/supported-gcp-types):

```
gcloud beta deployment-manager types list --project gcp-types
```

Or just `gcloud beta deployment-manager types list | grep function` helps.